# Regex for string that starts with a whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a regex: `\b[A-I]. .*`
Which searches for block like:

```
A. 1 to 2 
B. 2 to 3 
C. 3 to 4 
D. 4 to 5 
E. 5 to 6
```

It must find only this block and nothing further in text.
How can I force that this string is starting with whitespace?

Example here:
https://regex101.com/r/oW6iP9/1

Comment: You mean this: [`/^[A-I]\. .*$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/oW6iP9/2) ?

Comment: Yes! This is correct! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean this.

```
/^[A-I]\. .*/m
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oW6iP9/3)

Comment: /^[A-I]\. .*/gm - YES!

Comment: g is neede for my solution!

Answer (score 0):

This expression will work for you

```
^[A-I]\. .*/gm
```

`^` is the beginning of line, which must be combined with the `m` (multiline) option, so that each single line in the text is considered separatedly

`\.` use this instead of `.`, so that is interpreted as *dot*, and not as *any character*

`.*` will match everything but end of line, so that each match will end at the end of each line